# MOQ - Mock a Dictionary<string, double> object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, moq

I have the following setup for Moq:

```
... other code to setup bigMoq object ...
var innerMoq = new Mock<IDictionary<string, double>>();
innerMoq.SetupGet(d => d["COMPLEX"]).Returns(6d);
innerMoq.SetupGet(d => d["MEDIUM"]).Returns(8d);
innerMoq.SetupGet(d => d["SIMPLE"]).Returns(10d);
bigMoq.SetupGet(d => d.ComplexityWeights).Returns(x.Object);
```

When running a test method, I pass in bigMoq as the arguement.

The following works:

```
bigMoqVar.ComplexityWeights["COMPLEX"] // correctly returns 6
```

However, this does not:

```
bigMoqVar.ComplexityWeights.ContainsKey("COMPLEX")  // returns false instead of true
```

**What is the recommended way to support the ContainsKey on the innerMoq?**

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Dictionary<string,double>` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you didn't setup an expectation for `ContainsKey`. You will need to setup that manually, Moq has no knowledge of the semantics of the interface.

```
innerMoq.Setup(d => d.ContainsKey("COMPLEX")).Returns(true);
```

However, if this is just an `IDictionary` you need, why go through the mocking framework ? Just create a `Dictionary<string,double>` with the objects you need.

Comment: Thanks.  I was overzealous to use Moq I guess.  Creating a Dictionary instead worked perfectly.